# Reverse hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a Hash like this:

```
{ "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5"], ...}
```

How can I get a hash like this:

```
{ "value1" => "key_1", "value2" => "key_1", "value3" => "key_1", "value4" => "key_2", "value5" => "key_2" }
```

I have tried this:

```
Hash[original_hash.flat_map { |key, values| original_hash.map { |value| [value, key] } }]
```

Comment: Keep in mind the same value may be set for different keys. For instance take:
{ "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5", "value1"]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key,values),h| values.each { |v| h[v] = key } }
```

Comment: To allow the same value for multiple keys one could use `hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key,values),h| values.each { |v| h[v] = [h.fetch(v, []), key].flatten } }`.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the hash like normal:

```
h = { "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5"]}
newh = {}
h.each do |key, vals|
  vals.each { |v| newh[v] = key }
end

p newh
#=> {"value1"=>"key_1", "value2"=>"key_1", "value3"=>"key_1", "value4"=>"key_2", "value5"=>"key_2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this hash:

```
> h = { "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5"]}
=> {"key_1"=>["value1", "value2", "value3"], "key_2"=>["value4", "value5"]}
```

You could do:

```
> h.map{ |k, v| v.map{ |f| { f => k }}}.flatten
=> [{"value1"=>"key_1"}, {"value2"=>"key_1"}, {"value3"=>"key_1"}, {"value4"=>"key_2"}, {"value5"=>"key_2"}]
```

Updated answer:

```
> h.inject({}){ |h, (k,v)| v.each{ |f| h[f] = k }; h }
=> {"value1"=>"key_1", "value2"=>"key_1", "value3"=>"key_1", "value4"=>"key_2", "value5"=>"key_2"}
```

Comment: You can do: `h.inject({}){|h, (k,v)| v.map{|f| h[f] = k}; h}`

Comment: Something feels so wrong about map and reduce (inject) operations on hashes. It's a clever solution though.

Comment: @jmdeldin Is just looks unfamiliar because `map` is used where `each` would suffice.

Comment: Yes, `h.inject({}){|h, (k,v)| v.each{|f| h[f] = k}; h}` would work as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your hash:

```
Hash = { "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5"]}
```

I called your hash, "Hash", so that we can invert it. Inverting the hash switches the key and the value pair.

```
Hash ={ "key_1" => ["value1","value2","value3"], "key_2" => ["value4","value5"]}

inverseHash = Hash.invert
```

So, I called the inverted has, "inverseHash". If you puts, this inverseHash, you will get your result:

```
puts inverseHash
```

The above code outputs:

```
{["value1", "value2", "value3"]=>"key_1", ["value4", "value5"]=>"key_2"}
```